# On update: Login failed for SQL Server authenticated sysadm

Tags: sql-server, update, sql-server-2017, logins, standard-edition

I run into a weird bug?

User complained to me that he cannot anymore update certain tables in database. He had owner rights in database and the login was window login (ad-login). I tried elevating him to sysadm, checked all the rights and even deleted and added the login again. Still the problem continued.

I tried creating a SQL Server sysadm-login, so I wouldn't have to think about AD-issue and tried that. the same error consists. Both of the logins can login to SQL-instance, SELECT data, UPDATE certain tables but cannot UPDATE other ones.

Older logins (like mine) work fine on evertyhing, but the newer ones don't. I have no idea what could be causing this.

> Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
> Login failed for user 'xxxx'

Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31) (KB5016884) - 14.0.3456.2 (X64)   Sep  2 2022 11:01:50   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: I don't know could for example corruption/fragmentation in the sys. tables cause this? I checked the logins ffrom sys tables and they seem fine

Comment: What does the SQL Logs say for the specific reason for the login failure?

Comment: Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Login failed for user 'xxxx'  this is all I get

Comment: And the "failed" login doesn't even show on logs

Comment: That error message is obfuscated intentionally for security but it is automatically captured with more details in the [SQL Server Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16). Please follow the linked documentation on how to view the log, and you'd have to scroll to the time of when the error occurred.

Comment: Like I said. I don't see anything on logs. last log event is backup, over an hour ago even though I tested multiple times in the last 10 minutes

Comment: I'd recommend looking a little closer and double checking you're looking at the correct logs. That type of error definitely gets logged. Are the tables that fire this error message possibly remote via a Linked Server?...that could explain a lot of this.

Comment: No, I am on the server (localhost) that hosts the SQL-instance and database. So it is not networking issue. Also I and other older logins can run UPDATE without any error

Comment: I have checked SQL Server logs and Windows NT logs

Comment: Unfortunately your issue sounds too localized and you may just need to hire an expert to debug it. There's not much information to go off of here without being in front of the server. Only other idea I could think would be to provide the `UPDATE` statement, and maybe the execution plan for it from an account that it works for, but I doubt that'll show much. Any triggers on these tables?

Comment: No triggers. I checked for that already. I think I need to schedule maintenance window, so I can update to lastest CU and SSMS-version and hope that fixes it...

Comment: Yes, being on the latest CU for 2017 is probably a good idea.

Comment: Check if the table you are going to update is 'regular' table and not synonym to remote one via linked server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check if the table you are going to update is 'regular' table and not synonym to remote one via linked server –
> SergeyA

This was the problem. What I did was take a clone of the WM and span it up, without network access.  Immeadiately running the query I got an error msg

```
DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "XXX" returned message....
```

So indeed thete is some relation to a linked server and the login is missing rights there. Apparently the failed logins were logged there, so that explains why there are no errors on logs on the server that I tried to debug.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

This answer just desribe how I investigate the root cause/causes in these problems:

1. Using SQLProfiler define a trace having following events: Error Log, Event Log, Exception, User Error Message, RPC:Starting, SQL:BatchStarting.
2. Execute and wait to receive errors and
   check with RPC:Starting, SQL:BatchStarting events.

Basically if you succed to find this error using this SQLProfiler session, you have to search the RPC:Starting, SQL:BatchStarting events which are before error, events having same sesion_id (which is the SPID col). Check this picture for SPID col
[image]